# How to add code to every page from module

Tags: frontend, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I am developing a plugin, that inserts some JS code into every page of OpenCart. This code needs some variables, that are set in admin part of module (this part is already finished). But now I need to modify template, that on every page there would be a HTML snippet with my code inserted.

I have gone through many tutorials (most of them were for OpenCart 1.X) and did not find anything about how to do this.

Also I would prefer not to change OpenCart's core code, like some modules do, if possible.

Comment: You can use OCMOD for editing code without changing any of the core files. href="https://github.com/opencart/opencart/wiki/Modification-System